# Firebase Firestore Get Subcollections for each document in a collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My database has a collection of sections, each of which contain a subcollection of subsections.

Here's the array I need to create:

```
[
  {
    "sectiontitle": "first section",
    "sectiontype": "1",
    "__id__": "6jwwukHmOs1743yC13vH",
    "subsections": [
      {
        "desc": "blah blah blah",
        "__id__": "KTq4MJTEMbDfR33RoX9J"
      },
      {
        "desc": "blah blah blah",
        "__id__": "ASFSADFSAFSADFSADFFS"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "sectiontitle": "second section",
    "sectiontype": "1",
    "__id__": "5jwwDHEDOs1743yC13vG",
    "subsections": [
      {
        "desc": "blah blah blah",
        "__id__": "DFG4MJTEMbDfR33DDDDD"
      },
      {
        "desc": "blah blah blah",
        "__id__": "ASDFGHFSAFSADFSHJFRD"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

My code is:

```
    // get sections
    firebase.firestore().collection("sections").get().then((sections) => {
      var myarray = [];
      var i = 0;
      sections.forEach((section) => {
        var sectiondata = section.data();
        sectiondata.__id__ = section.id
        sectiondata.subsections = [];
        myarray.push(sectiondata);

        //get subsections
        firebase.firestore().collection("sections").doc(sectiondata.__id__).collection("subsections").get().then((subsections) => {
          subsections.forEach((subsection) => {
            var subsectiondata = subsection.data();
            subsectiondata.__id__ = subsection.id;
            myarray.push('sections.' + i + '.subsections', subsectiondata); // problem is i index is not correct
          });
        });

        i++;

      });
    });
```

This problem is that the `i` index is not correct as the sections read has already finished and looped through the foreach by the time the subsections read has started. I'm not familiar with Javascript promises so I was hoping someone can help me out with how to solve this problem?

Basically, for each section, add the subsections.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Pls try this and let me know if worked correctly or not. Notice that SubjectBehavior is imported from RxJs library, and my code is a typescript code, as i think u r using typescript.

```
   sb = new SubjectBehavior<[]>();
    var basicArray = [];
           firebase.firestore().collection("sections").get().then((sections) => {
              var myarray = [];
              basicArray = [];
              var count = 0;

              sections.forEach((section) => {
                var sectiondata = section.data();
                sectiondata.__id__ = section.id
                sectiondata.subsections = [];
                myarray.push(sectiondata);
            count++;
            if( count === sections.length()) {
                sb.next(myarray); //or .emit(), i dont remember
            }
                //get subsections

            });

        sb.subscribe( (myArrayElements: any[]) => {
            myArrayElement.foreach( (element) => {
    firebase.firestore().collection("sections").doc(element.__id__).collection("subsections").get().then((subsections) => {
                      subsections.forEach((subsection) => {
                        var subsectiondata = subsection.data();
                        subsectiondata.__id__ = subsection.id;
                        basicArray.push('here element data (sectionData)' + '' + '.subsections', subsectiondata); 
                      });
                    });

                  });
    });
    });
```