# How can I get array and map object inside a collection of documents?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My firebase project has below firestore collection.

```
{
  name: "ninja250r",
  maker: "kawasaki",
  reserves: [
    0 : [
      id: "1",
      start_datetime: "2019-09-11 12:00:00",
      end_datetime: "2019-09-11 17:00:00",
    ]
    1 : [
      id: "2",
      start_datetime: "2019-09-11 12:00:00",
      end_datetime: "2019-09-11 17:00:00",
    ]
  ]
}
```

routes/bikes.js

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  db.collection('bikes').get()
  .then(snapshot => {
    var bikes = new Array();
    snapshot.forEach(doc => {
      bikes.push({
        id: doc.id,
        bikes: doc.data(),
      })
    })
    res.render('bikes', {
        title: 'all bikes',
        bike: bikes
    });
    console.log(bikes);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    next(err);
  });
});
```

view/bikes.pug

```
ul
  each item in bike
    li id:#{item.id}
      br
      | name:#{item.bikes.name}
      br
      | reserves:#{item.bikes.reserves}
```

And run
`$firebase serve`
log shows below

```
>  [ { id: '1',
>      bikes: { name: 'ninja250r', reserves: [Array], maker: 'kawasaki' } },
```

website show below.

```
id:1
name:ninja250r
reserves:[object Object],[object Object]
```

I want to show reserve array(id,start_datetime,end_datetime), but I don't know what to do.
How can I display reserve?

I tried another method of using subcollection, but I could not get subcollection in collection at the same time.

reference link
[Firebase Firestore Get Subcollections for each document in a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54708841/firebase-firestore-get-subcollections-for-each-document-in-a-collection)

Comment: It looks like `reserves` is an array type field, not a subcollection.  Treat it like an array.

Comment: @DougStevenson I know. But I don't know how can I display array on website.